# SQL Database - query to produce a list of doctor IDs and their names with the number of appointments they have?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables; doctor, person, and appointment. 
doctor table:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
| doctor_id | phone_no | room_no | date_qualified | date_appointed |
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
| 50        | 1234     | 1       | 1963-09-01     | 1991-05-10     |
| 51        | 1235     | 2       | 1973-09-12     | 1991-05-10     |
| 52        | 1236     | 3       | 1990-10-02     | 1993-04-01     |
| 53        | 1237     | 4       | 1965-06-30     | 1994-03-01     |
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
```

**person table**

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
| person_id | initials | last_name | date_of_birth | sex  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
| 100       | T        | Williams  | 1972-01-12    | m    |
| 101       | J        | Garcia    | 1981-03-18    | f    |
| 102       | W        | Fisher    | 1950-10-22    | m    |
| 103       | K        | Waldon    | 1942-06-01    | m    |
| 104       | P        | Timms     | 1928-06-03    | m    |
| 105       | A        | Dryden    | 1944-06-23    | m    |
| 106       | F        | Fogg      | 1955-10-16    | f    |
| 150       | T        | Saj       | 1994-06-17    | m    |
| 50        | A        | Cameron   | 1937-04-04    | m    |
| 51        | B        | Finlay    | 1948-12-01    | m    |
| 52        | C        | King      | 1965-06-06    | f    |
| 53        | D        | Waldon    | 1938-07-08    | f    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
```

**appointment table**

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| doctor_id | patient_id | appt_date  | appt_time | appt_duration |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 50        | 100        | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 100        | 1994-08-16 | 10:50:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 102        | 1994-08-21 | 11:20:00  |            20 |
| 50        | 103        | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 104        | 1994-08-10 | 10:20:00  |            20 |
| 52        | 102        | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  |            10 |
| 52        | 105        | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  |            10 |
| 52        | 150        | 2014-03-10 | 12:00:00  |            15 |
| 53        | 106        | 1994-08-10 | 11:30:00  |            10 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to create a query to produce a list of `doctor IDs` and their names with the number of appointments they have.

I have already created a statement to produce a list of doctor IDs with the number of appointments they have but im not sure how to produce a list with doctor IDs and their names.

The statement that I have now is:

```
select doctor.doctor_id, count(appointment.appt_time) as no_appt
from doctor
left join appointment
on doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id
group by doctor.doctor_id;
```

Please Help.

Comment: your code is looking good. you should just add the field like `initials,last_name`with `left join` in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional join to the `person` table.  Apparently, the `doctor_id` is the link.  Yuck.  This should be an explicit column rather than a re-use of the id.

```
select d.doctor_id, p.initials, p.last_name, count(appointment.appt_time) as no_appt
from doctor d left join
     appointment a
     on d.doctor_id = a.doctor_id left join
     person p
     on d.doctor_id = p.person_id
group by d.doctor_id, p.initials, p.last_name;
```

In MySQL, you don't actually need to add the two columns to the `group by`, but it is good practice to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
select doctor.doctor_id, person.initials, person.last_name, count(appointment.appt_time) as no_appt
from doctor 
left join appointment on doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id
left join person on person.person_id = appointment.patient_id 
group by doctor.doctor_id;
```

Comment: this SQL won't work because doctor table does not have initials or last_name columns - these are on the Person table

Answer (score 1):

your SQL is nearly there - you just need to add a JOIN to the Person table to get the initial and last_name of the doctors - like this:

```
SELECT 
    d.doctor_id, 
    p.initials,
    p.last_name,
    COUNT(a.*)
FROM [person] p
JOIN [doctor] d ON p.person_id = d.doctor_id
LEFT JOIN [appointment] a ON a.doctor_id = d.doctor_id
GROUP BY d.doctor_id, p.initials, p.last_name
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When I use this statement, in the Doctor name field i dont get the names it just shows zeros.

Comment: You're using MySQL? Try this: 
`code` 
CONCAT(p.initials,'.',p.last_name) as [Doctor Name]
`code` replacing the line in the SQL above

Comment: so what would you put after group by

Comment: Hi - sorry, you would group by CONCAT(p.initials,'.',p.last_name) - let me know if that works

Comment: In which case, you can separate out the initials and last_name columns rather than trying to concatenate them - I've updated my answer above to reflect this. Are you getting an error message?